# Use string as record index in template with ember.js and ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to access a specific property of a record in an each-loop in a template.

Simplified code:
Part of my model:

```
App.Signature = DS.Model.extend({
    facebook: DS.attr('string'),
    google: DS.attr('string')
});
```

In my controller I have this array:

```
social: [
    {index: 'facebook', name: 'Facebook'},
    {index: 'google', name: 'Google+'}
]
```

Now in my template I tried something like this:

```
{{#each item in social}}
    {{input type="url" value=signature.[item.index]}}
{{/each}}
```

Which apparently does not work. How to achieve this?

Thank you very much for your help.